# How to randomize a different number for each dice?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a mini version of a yatzy game, just to learn some loops and if statements. This is how far I've gotten. Now I'm kind of stuck though because:

1) When I click the roll dices button it displays the same number on all 6 dices. How do I make it so that a different number is randomized for each dice?

2) I can only click the roll dices button once, if I want to roll it another time I have to reload the page in order to do so. Why is that?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
<script src="myjavascript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<button id="button" onclick="rolldices()">Roll dices</button>

<span id="dice1">0</span>
<span id="dice2">0</span>
<span id="dice3">0</span>
<span id="dice4">0</span>
<span id="dice5">0</span>
<span id="dice6">0</span>


<br><br><br>
<div id="container">
<div id="one">1</div>           <span>0</span>
<div id="two">2</div>           <span>0</span>
<div id="three">3</div>         <span>0</span>
<div id="four">4</div>          <span>0</span>
<div id="five">5</div>          <span>0</span>
<div id="six">6</div>           <span>0</span>
<div id="total">Total</div>     <span>0</span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var numbers = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ];

var dices = [ 'dice1', 'dice2', 'dice3', 'dice4', 'dice5', 'dice6' ];

var dice_value = Math.floor((Math.random()*numbers.length));

function rolldices() {

for (var diceindex=0; diceindex<dices.length; diceindex++) {

document.getElementById("dice" + (diceindex + 1)).innerHTML=numbers[dice_value];

}

} // end of rolldices()
```

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h26DD/

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with programming, but "dice" is the plural of "die" ;-)

Comment: It's my 2nd language so I couldn't care less lol.

Comment: @Grim... Also, calling it DICE makes it easier to read if ur not english/american tbh :P

Comment: Try now: http://jsfiddle.net/ZL4fN/. This is what @Grim suggest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `var dice_value = Math.floor((Math.random()*numbers.length));` inside the loop, or it will be the same all the time.

Comment: I even tried that before I posted but it didn't work but when I tried it a 2nd time it did.. what the f...

Comment: It's like when you try and plug in a sub lead, and it doesn't fit, so you turn it over, and it still doesn't fit, so you turn it over again, and then it fits :-S